# S3 access control based on bucket tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

i hope you can help me out. I have read a [couple](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html) [of](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html#amazons3-policy-keys) [docs](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_iam-tags.html) now, and I am still unsure whether this actually works.

I want to give access in different levels to AWS users based on S3 tags.

Example:

- S3 bucket `mybucket` has tags `{"access-team-dev": "rwd"}`, which should lead to the "dev" team having "read, write, delete" access.
- one tag for each team, the value is the access level.

I have tried at least 10 different combinations of this IAM policy:

```json
[
    {
        "Action": [ "a lot of actions removed for brevity" ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {"aws:ResourceTag/access-team-dev": ["list","ro","rw","rwd"]}
        },
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Action": [ "a lot of actions removed for brevity" ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {"aws:ResourceTag/access-team-dev": ["ro","rw","rwd"]}
        },
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Action": [ "a lot of actions removed for brevity" ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {"aws:ResourceTag/access-team-dev": ["rw","rwd"]}
        },
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Action": [ "a lot of actions removed for brevity" ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {"aws:ResourceTag/access-team-dev": ["rwd"]}
        },
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

... but nothing works.

That policy is assigned to the user via a IAM group, the test bucket is tagged with "access-team-dev": "rwd".

Two questions:

- does that work **at all**??
- if yes, what am i doing wrong???

Really frustrating, cause according to the docs - if I read them correctly - this *should* work, right?

Thanks for all answers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a *lot* more googling I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53912556) StackOverflow post, which references [these AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html). *Implicitly* it seems that there is no way to grant *bucket* level access using tags, whereas you can grant *object* level access.

Which means, given you *have* access to a bucket, you can control which objects a user can Read/Write/etc. (based on the `...ObjectTag` conditions).

At least I *think* that is the current state of things. Which is unfortunate, but apparently true.

Date of writing: 2022-12-09